# Using a Remote Deskdop Connection to run Python, empty html files

Tags: python, html, virtual-machine, anaconda, userappdatapath

I am trying to run my python files from a Remote Desktop Connection (virtual machine?). I copied over a few folders I thought would be relevant and ran Anaconda to install python and the add-ons.

My code runs, but the output is html files and in the VM they are empty. I checked the code for the html and it looks like it writes information from my local C:\ drive. For example, this is a snippet from the html: `BEGIN C:\Users\jbyrusb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bokeh\server\static\css/bokeh.min.css`

I tried to copy the AppData folder over to the VM. Still, the html files come up empty.

Does anyone know why/ a better way to move my things onto a VM? This is my first time using one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Internet Explorer on the VM was very old and therefore not running the html code properly. Updated to Firefox and it worked!